# How to see code changes after git pull?

Tags: git

I would like to inspect any code changes after doing a `git pull`. Currently it's just showing me which files changes. How can I see what code changed?

Comment: Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362952/detail-change-after-git-pull).

Comment: Search for answer "Just after a pull". The accepted answer does not answer what to do _after_ doing a `git pull`

Answer (score 151, accepted):

```
git log --name-status -2
```

Will show you the names of the files that changed for the last two commits.

```
git log -p -2
```

Will show you the changes themselves.

Before you pull,

```
git fetch
git log --name-status origin/master..
```

Will show you what commits you are about to retrieve, along with the names of the files.

Comment: Based upon this reply the command "git log --graph -p" is doing a nice job. It shows tree information about the history and code changes as well. Furthermore you can scroll up and down without any extra tool or gitk.

Answer (score 114):

### Before pulling

You can review changes as @iblue says with a `fetch` and `diff` before merging:

```
$ git fetch
$ git diff master...origin/master
```

Note the triple period, which means diff against the shared parent and origin/master (commits marked `x` below):

```
SP---o---o [master]
  \
   x---x [origin/master]
```

### Just after a pull

The very first line in the output of a pull looks like this:

```
$ git pull
Updating 37b431a..b2615b4
...
```

You can then simply do:

```
$ git diff 37b431a..b2615b4
```

Or whatever other command:

```
$ git log --name-status 37b431a..b2615b4
```

### Later on

If it has been a while since you pulled, and you wish to know what changes were brought in by the last pull, you can look it up with:

```
$ git reflog | grep -A1 pull | head -2
```

which will show the hash after the pull followed by the hash before the pull:

```
b2615b4 HEAD@{0}: pull : Fast-forward
37b431a HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from v6.1 to master
```

You can then do the same thing with these two hashes:

```
git diff 37b431a..b2615b4
```

Comment: This is the only answer that allows you to check which files have changed during the last pull when you don't remember how many commits were pulled at that time.

Answer (score 31):

Because `git pull` is just a shortcut for `git fetch` and `git merge`, you can run `git fetch` to fetch the branches from the origin and then show the differences before merging. Like this:

```
git fetch                      # Load changes from remote server
git diff master origin/master  # Show differences
git merge origin/master        # Merge remote changes with local changes
```

If you run on a different branch than *master*, you should of course change the branch names in the commands above.

Comment: ``` git diff --name-only master origin/master [path] ```

Comment: This is gold. we can see what is going to get merged

Answer (score 18):

You can compare the pulled contents with the sources of immediately previous commit by,

```
git diff branch_name@{1}
```

eg:

```
git diff master@{1}
```

For comparing with the sources n commits behind,

```
git diff branch_name@{n}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but the explanation is incorrect: *"For comparing with the sources n commits behind"*. The `@{n}` syntax actually means the `nth` previous **position** of the branch/head. For example, if there have been 10 commits since the last time you did a pull, `master@{1}` would refer to the prior **position** of `master`, which is 10 **commits** prior. This is why using `@{n}` is useful for checking changes after a pull.

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for! Thanks for explanation @wisbucky

Comment: Equivalent simpler form for n-th previous commit on *master* branch: `master^n`

Comment: this should be chosen as the right answer!

Answer (score 5):

You can check what get change while push and pull by this...

```
git log --stat
```

Comment: you can't see code changes with this. Only who made the commit, which files were changed date of commit and stuff like that

Answer (score 0):

Best way to compare status before and after a pull (after the pull has been done):

```
git diff master^1
```

Or more generically:

```
git diff <branch name>^<commits back>
```