# Need to get the details of the modified files in GitPull method in cake script

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp, cakebuild

Hi I am using GitPull method to pull the changes into Repository.

Referred from below link

http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Git/GitAliases/CC1AE32F

I need to get the log of updated files while performing GitPull method.

Is there any way to get those details using below page or suggest some other way to perform above action in cake.

http://cakebuild.net/dsl/git/

Answer (score 3):

First a disclaimer because of an previous issue with merges in Cake.Git / Libgit2sharp you'll need to upgrade to version `0.14.0` or later of `Cake.Git` for this answer to work.

Easiest way to get changes files reliably regardless of fast forward merge or not is to:

1. Get commit before pull
2. Do the pull
3. If repo wasn't up to date Get commit after pull
4. Do a diff between before and after pull commit

The `Cake.Git` way of doing this would be

1. [GitLogTip](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Git/GitAliases/4AE932FF)
2. [GitPull](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Git/GitAliases/CC1AE32F)
3. If [pullResult](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Git/GitMergeResult/).[Status](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Git/GitMergeResult/8D40B184)!=[GitMergeStatus](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Git/GitMergeStatus/).[UpToDate](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Git/GitMergeStatus/12AA552D) then [GitLogTip](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Git/GitAliases/4AE932FF)
4. [GitDiff](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Git/GitAliases/CAD727C5)

This could look something like below

```
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Git&version=0.14.0

DirectoryPath repoDir = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./Cake_Git"));

string  name    = "John Doe",
        email   = "john@doe.com";

var beforePullCommit = GitLogTip(repoDir);

var pullResult = GitPull(repoDir, name, email);

if (pullResult.Status!=GitMergeStatus.UpToDate)
{
    var afterPullCommit = GitLogTip(repoDir);

    var diff = GitDiff(repoDir, beforePullCommit.Sha, afterPullCommit.Sha);

    foreach(var file in diff)
    {
        Information("{0}", file);
    }
}
```

[GitDiff](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Git/GitAliases/CAD727C5) returns an ICollection of [GitDiffFile](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Git/GitDiffFile/)s which has these properties.

```
Name        Value           Summary
Exists      bool            The file exists in the new side of the diff.
OldExists   bool            The file exists in the old side of the diff.
OldPath     string          The old path.
Path        string          The new path.
Status      GitChangeKind   The kind of change that has been done
                            (added, deleted, modified ...).
```

and has an ToString() override sp the output of this script would look something like this

```
Path: ReleaseNotes.md, OldPath: ReleaseNotes.md, Status: Modified, Exists: True, OldExists: True
Path: src\Cake.Git\Cake.Git.csproj, OldPath: src\Cake.Git\Cake.Git.csproj, Status: Modified, Exists: True, OldExists: True
Path: src\Cake.Git\GitMergeResult.cs, OldPath: src\Cake.Git\GitMergeResult.cs, Status: Modified, Exists: True, OldExists: True
Path: src\Cake.Git\packages.config, OldPath: src\Cake.Git\packages.config, Status: Modified, Exists: True, OldExists: True
Path: src\SolutionInfo.cs, OldPath: src\SolutionInfo.cs, Status: Modified, Exists: True, OldExists: True
```

but as it's an typed object you could do of course to a lot more programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

> while performing GitPull method.

You could try [*after* a git pull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11284409/6309) (which is fetch plus merge), with (non-Cake solution)

```
git log --stat
```

Or, as mentioned with [**Fun with `FETCH_HEAD`**](http://gitster.livejournal.com/28309.html)

```
git log --name-only ..FETCH_HEAD
```

I don't see those options supported in [Cake GitLog](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Git/GitAliases/469FCAAF) method, so you can try at least parse the result of:

```
var result = GitLog("c:/temp/cake", 1);
```

(that is the last merge commit generated by `git pull`)

Comment: Hi @Vonc

when i executes the below command in cmd it generates the log

`git pull --stat >../GitLogs/dashboard-service.txt`

but the same command doesn't generate the log in either c# or cake

Comment: Cant  do it in c#
             `string path= @"G:\Gitlab\sfinput-xaml";

            System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(path);

            Process p = new Process();

            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe";

            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "pull --stat >../GitLogs/log.txt";

            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            p.Start();`
Error:

**fatal: '>../GitLogs/log.txt' does not appear to be a git repository 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.**

Comment: @JeevaS Make sure your process does execute itself in the Git repo path: http://stackoverflow.com/a/114937/6309

Comment: I have set Git repository as current directory. when i execute `git clean -xdf` command it works..even `git pull stat`also works..But while trying to write log facing the above issue.

Comment: @JeevaS `var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();`   `startInfo.WorkingDirectory = // working directory`
`// set additional properties` 
`Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);`

Comment: tried like below..but still same issue
 `var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"G:\Gitlab\sfinput-xaml";
            startInfo.Arguments= "pull --stat >../GitLogs/log.txt";
            startInfo.FileName = "Git";
            Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo)`

Comment: @JeevaS Try specify the full path for your log.txt

Comment: facing **fatal: Invalid refspec G:/GitLogs/log.txt** issue

Comment: @JeevaS I suspect the output redirection (`>`) is not directly supported on process. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/q/285760/6309