# How to move class files from one repo to another while both are being actively developed

Tags: git, intellij-idea

So I have three projects, two existing and one new. The two existing let's call them A and B. A and B are being actively developed by other people. I am creating a new project C that only I initially will be working on.

What I need to do is move files some files from B to A as well as others from B to C. A and B will contain an artifact for C after this whole process is complete. My problem is there is a significant risk I will miss a change from another developer that occurs to one of the files I pull out of B unless I can find an approach that can track changes to a file across projects.

I have looked into using the git subtree mechanism, however, I am having a hard time finding any documentation for getting IntelliJ to play nice with    Git subtrees. Even if I did it seems like the process for pulling in changes to the subtree projects from upstream is not straightforward if you need to make changes to the subtree projects.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is: do you need to complete history of those files or simply do you need to make sure you are working with the latest version?

In that latter case, all you need to do is keep a copy of A and B somewhere, do a pull regularly and [check the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11284366/6309) to see if any of your files have been impacted.
You can decide and report those changes if relevant, through a [third-party diff/merge tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools).

The point is: there is no easy mechnism in Git where files are imported (possibly with a different destination path) *and* modified, while having evolution in their original repos.