# How to hide unmodified files while check in Github

Tags: github

I am using Github in our Project.

When I am checking in Github to pull data from original master it is displaying all the files but I need the files which are changed by me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) to display updated files by author.
See for instance "[Can I get git to tell me all the files one user has modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6349405/6309)"

```
git log --pretty="%H" --author="authorname"
```

(replace `authorname` by your own, as you specified it in `git config user.name`)

[After a pull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1362990/6309), you can log between `master@{1}` and `master`.