# Git log after pull

Tags: git, git-pull, git-log

When you run `pull` command (and if it succeeds) it shows you something like this:

`984ed83..af3ad3c  master     -> origin/master`

and then I usually run `git lg` which is my alias I set for

`log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit`

this shows the log in "easy to read" way. Although I still need to scan the log with my eyes and find the first hash and then read everything upward from that point.

[image]

Now I'm wondering if it's possible, after a successful pull to see log but only from the last changed hash up to the head?

Comment: you can write a client side hook

Comment: What about `git lg 984ed83..af3ad3c`?

Comment: @franz you still have to do it "manually". Is there a "smarter" way, something like `git log ~last_pull..HEAD`

Comment: Try `git log master@{1}..master` or `git log HEAD@{1}..HEAD` depending on what do you want to see. Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1362990/878514)?

Comment: ummm this is interesting. so what exactly `@{1}` means here? apparently it works. Although `HEAD@{1}..HEAD` didn't work for repo where I'm not in the master branch

Comment: `@{1}` refers to the second entry in the *reflog* (`git reflog`). That log is updated essentially whenever HEAD changes, so it *can* be used for looking at how the branches looked in past. But just using `@{1}` is not a safe way to refer to the commit before the merge here.

Comment: what about `ORIG_HEAD..HEAD`, can I use that?

Comment: Yeah, that should work.